# How to write query that how much customer A borrowed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i have following tables account, branch, customer, loan, borrower, depositor..

how can write query that  how much 'customerA' borrowed?

I tried by writing

```
select borrower.customer_name, loan.amount from borrower, loan
where borrower.loan_number=loan.loan_number and customer_name = 'customerA';
```

Its showing no rows selected
I am new to querying ..pls help

Comment: Looks like customer A hasn't borrowed anything.

Comment: People ask *Siri*, and *Siri* ask in SO :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I prefer to ask Sevy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FLiRw7sAJI He won't lie to you, even if it's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax:

Also help if you use alias.

```
select B.customer_name, L.amount 
from borrower as B
inner join loan as L
   ON B.loan_number = L.loan_number
where  
   B.customer_name = 'customerA';
```

As  sstan suggest the query looks ok. Try to remove the where part and see if there is any data on just the join result.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. All you've done is rewritten the query in a slightly different way.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp As I say the query looks ok, and suggest remove the where clause to see if the query is returning right data. No much more I can do to help. If you have a better answer please post it.